# Need emergency help with dw20.exe process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

recently I have deployed asp.net application to production windows server 2008.

after 10-20 min, starts dw20.exe process (Microsoft.net error reporting shim), which takes almost all CPU available which cause to very slow response of my application.

No error no exception in Event Viewer.

I right clicked on the dw20.exe process and created the dump file to analyze what causing the issue.

Then I opened this file in WidDbg. run command .loadby sos mscorwks and get Unable to find module 'mscorwks'

It looks like I'm missing something or doing it wrong.

How to determine what cause an exception in application? how to analyze DMP file created?

Is it possible to stop this service?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding ELMAH (http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to the project so that you can grab the error info in an easier fashion.

Comment: in case if error happen I'm capturing it in Global file.  but no error

Answer (score 1):

When we get hit by rogue CPU, we use [Sam Saffron's CPU analyzer](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2009/11/11/Diagnosing+runaway+CPU+in+a+Net+production+application) to see what it is busy doing. Most times it turns out to be a bad regex (no, seriously; this bites too often for comfort).

Comment: Thank you Marc for your suggestion. I have tried to use this application on process dw20.exe but it couldn't get any info during 40 sec the process was alive. I tried on another w3wp process and it works. Do you know how to disable the error process not to start dw20?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that one of the method caused recursive loop.